# How to overwrite StringHttpMessageConverter DEFAULT_CHARSET to use UTF8 in spring 4

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8

I am trying to make spring @ResponseBody return always utf-8. But I can't do it for so long.
Problem comes when I am returning simple text answer:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String ajaxTest() {
    return "Characters test: ęółąśżźćń";
}
```

Each polish chars (ęółąśżźćń) goes to `?`

And in web page I am getting this string:
`Characters test: ?�???????` instead of `Characters test: ęółąśżźćń`

I don't know what I am missing.

I've added custome bean to `public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {}`
Which goes as follows:

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<String> responseBodyConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    return converter;
}
```

Instruction taken from
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9099

But it doesn't work. I can see in firefox and chrome that returned value is in utf-8:
[image]

---

Spring version: 4.1.1.RELEASE

Web app config class:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

//import com.derp.common.wicketView.HomePage;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.derp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARSET = "hibernate.connection.CharSet";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARACTERENCODING = "hibernate.connection.characterEncoding";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_USEUNICODE = "hibernate.connection.useUnicode";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES = "services.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON = "common.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS = "cms.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_PROCEDURE = "procedure.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_PROCEDURE)
                });
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARSET, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARSET));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARACTERENCODING, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_CHARACTERENCODING));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_USEUNICODE, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_CONNECTION_USEUNICODE));
        properties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        // Simple strategy: only path extension is taken into account
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
            ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
            useJaf(false).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
            mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
            mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/img/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/lib/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/lib/*");
    }



    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        converters.add(responseBodyConverter());
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<String> responseBodyConverter() {
        StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Application initializer:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        ctx.register(ThymeleafConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);     
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerCharachterEncodingFilter(servletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
    }


    private void registerCharachterEncodingFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter cef = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        cef.setForceEncoding(true);
        cef.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        aContext.addFilter("charachterEncodingFilter", cef).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }
    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }

}
```

Java script/Jquery ajax call

```
  $('h1').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: "/derp/procedury/test",
          data: "none",
          success: function (response, status, xhr) {
              showNotifications(status, xhr.responseText);
          },
          error: function (response, status, xhr) {
              showNotifications('error', JSON.stringify(response));
              showNotifications('error', status);
              showNotifications('error', xhr);
          }
      });
  });
```

Please help.

Comment: How are you consuming the response body?

Comment: I don understand Your question. Can You extend Your question?

Comment: Where do you see the `?????` ? Are you seeing it in the browser? Are you receiving it in an ajax response handler?

Comment: I am getting it in html in web browser, in the place where I expect to be polish utf-8 chars

Answer (score 5):

Your Network tab seems to be showing

```
text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

which isn't what you configured it to be

```
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

It seems your custom `HttpMessageConverter` bean isn't getting registered. Add this to your `WebAppConfig` class

```
@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(responseBodyConverter());
}
```

You should see your response contain

```
Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
```

I can't explain why your browser's network tab would show `UTF-8` but wouldn't be able to parse or render it properly. It works fine for me.

Comment: unfortunatelly. Error that I get:`HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request \"accept\" headers.` 
and`","status":406,"statusText":"Not Acceptable"}`
the response is still: `Content-Type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"`

Comment: I've made `configureMessageConverters`  public, cause of compilation error. Dont know is it matter?

Comment: @masterdany88 Your `accept` header accepts everything. That error should not happen. Which compilation error? Making it public doesn't matter, but it shouldn't be needed. Please edit your question and add a full reproducible example. Please also specify your Spring version.

Comment: Ok. Updated. Hope it will be everythink needed. Compilation error came when method configureMessageConverters was protected. Making it public resolve it.

Comment: @masterdany88 Oh, you were using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. I was using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. You might want to look into that, it has more options. I'll continue to look at your problem soon.

Comment: After switching to WebMvcConfigurationSupport all my css and js lost mapping. Can check it without Jquery.

Comment: @masterdany88 Don't forget to implement the appropriate corresponding methods that you had in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. They might not have the same names.

Comment: Ok. After removing: `@EnableWebMvc` annotation it works.But I am getting `406 Not acceptable`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `StringHttpMessageConverter` defaults to ISO-8859-1. You need either set the default to UTF-8 as shown here:

```
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter<String> responseBodyConverter() {
        StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
        return converter;
    }
```

Or get the client to specify exactly what they want with the `Accept` header, ie: `Accept: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem as others have stated is that `StringHttpMessageConverter` defaults to ISO-8859-1.

I just replaced the default charset of existing StringHttpMessageConverter to UTF-8

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SampleWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream()
            .filter(converter -> converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter)
            .forEach(converter -> ((StringHttpMessageConverter) converter).setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```